# Mutually Exclusive Bootstrap Checkbox Switches

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I have this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joshuadickerson92/s537t380/3/) with two checkboxes using Bootstrap Switch. I would like them to be mutually exclusive, i.e neither of them can be on or off at the same time. Is this possible without using the radio button class?

Current checkbox code as per below:

```
$("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch({
onSwitchChange: function (event, state) {

    if(state) map.addLayer(streetsTile);
    else map.removeLayer(streetsTile);
}
});

$("[name='my-checkbox2']").bootstrapSwitch({
onSwitchChange: function (event, state) {

    if(state) map.addLayer(exampleTile);
    else map.removeLayer(exampleTile);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For instance like so:

```
$("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch({
    onSwitchChange: function (event, state) {
        $("[name='my-checkbox2']").bootstrapSwitch('state', !state, true);
        if(state) map.addLayer(streetsTile);
        else map.removeLayer(streetsTile);
    }
});

$("[name='my-checkbox2']").bootstrapSwitch({
    onSwitchChange: function (event, state) {
        $("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch('state', !state, true);
        if(state) map.addLayer(exampleTile);
        else map.removeLayer(exampleTile);
    }
});
```

But why don't you want to use the radio buttons for this ...?

Comment: Thanks, the examples i'd seen using radio buttons all had the same radio button names which wouldn't work for my example, is it possible to use radio buttons with different names?

Comment: Maybe not, but you could put the name inside the button (`labelText`).